# How to save a canvas in list in programe and then iterate it to display objects on it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a canvas with multiple canvases and I am saving them to a list. Now I want them to be displayed on a refreshed pages from that list. I don't know how to put Tkinter canvas objects stored in a list on to a frame please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, as there is really nothing special you need to do. List items work just like normal variables.

For example, this will create 10 canvases and put them in a list:

```
canvases = []
for i in range(10):
    canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
    canvases.append(canvas)
```

You can later put all of those canvases in a frame by iterating over the list. For example, this uses `pack` but you can of course use `grid` or `place` or call any other methods you want:

```
for canvas in canvases:
    canvas.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Comment: yes,actually I am showing a download page in tkinter I have created a canvas consisting of canvases of downloaded file details and now I am showing current downloading item on that frame.But it disappears when I change the page.So I thought to save canvases in a list and then on coming back to that page display them from the list.Thank you but this approach is not working I tried to do as you have shown.